# python django: login with office 365

Tags: python, django, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, python-social-auth

I am trying to implement a office365/azureAD/MS graph authentication system for a Django website.

My University has a office365 account system for all students. If you log in using your ID for that you get access to all MS Office software and other university systems.

Looks like this:
[image]

I'm trying to make it so that students can log into my website using this system. Rather than me implementing a user/password model and associated views etc.

I feel like I've been going around in circles.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it with [django-social-auth](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html) and its [AzureAD backend](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/azuread.html).

You'd need to [register your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications) in AzureAD. It sounds like you'd need to ask your University's IT department to do that part for you.

Comment: do you think it might be possible to use the google back end as shown in the docs `<a href="{% url "social:begin" "google-oauth2" %}">Google+</a>`

and then swap out the details like key and secret later if I can get the Uni to agree to register my app?

I have also found the django-allauth package which seems to do the same job.

Comment: You can support multiple backends with it. Switching out would maybe be possible with some work. You'd have to be able to associate the Office 365 accounts to their respective Google accounts somehow.